# How to do permanent (301) redirection from LWC/Aura to an external website URL (and set redirectCode as 301)

Tags: lightning-web-components, url, navigationmixin.navigate, community-cloud, redirection

Custom URL redirect requirement as OOTB URL redirect is not an option due to many limitations org has.

**Requirement** - To redirect every URL of a custom subdomain of an experience site to an **external website url** (in the same tab/window and not with a new tab/window)  with a Status of ***301 Moved Permanently*** for google indexing needs.

Is there any attribute that can be set in LWC-NavigationMixin to achieve [setRedirectCode(redirectCode)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirectCode.htm) ?

Below code works for redirecting using LWC but it's not a 301 redirection.

```
connectedCallback() {
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: '[External website URL]'
        }
    }).then(generatedUrl => {
        window.open(generatedUrl,"_self");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done because a status code response comes from a server, and in this scenario you are doing things on the client side entirely.

Answer (score -3):

This can be done with - `window.location.replace(External website URL)`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you _really sure_ about this? Do you have some documentation to back this claim up? This seems to me like something Lightning Locker might prevent. If Locker is fine with is, does this result in a 301 like the question is asking for?

Comment: Unlikely something like this wouldn't have been documented for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace). There will be plenty of material online contradicting your answer, just look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846738/are-301-redirects-possible-using-javascript-or-jquery).